# Access file names(or mappings) from specific dependency in sbt

Tags: sbt

I would like to access all of the content of one of my dependencies during the build. To be more precise, I want to include the scaladoc of one of my dependencies into a site generated with `sbt-site`. I think I could do that with `mappings` or `addMappingsToSiteDir` as described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-site/getting-started.html) but for that I need to be able to get mappings of this dependency somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with following code.

```
(update in Compile).value
    .select(configurationFilter("provided"))
    .filter(x => x.name.contains(s"mypackage") && x.name.contains(s"javadoc"))
    .flatMap(unpackjar(_, target.value / "mypackage"))

def unpackjar(jar: File, to: File): Seq[(File, String)] = {
  println(s"Processing $jar and saving to $to")
  IO.unzip(jar, to)
  Path.allSubpaths(to).toSeq
}
```